# Plotly.js: plotly_click event when using WebGL

Tags: plotly

The documentation of plotly.js gives an example for intercepting the click event: https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/.

The event is intercepted by attaching a `plotly_click` event to the main `div` of the plot.

The sample on the documentation uses the plot 'scatter' but the feature should works also on the WebGL version (see item **240** in https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/c53a00a6c8f9fa84f13702527d955490020eae0c/CHANGELOG.md)

**The problem**:

I worked out this sample, but the `plotly_click`, but the event is not triggered.Interestingly, it works  if I substitue `scatter_gl` with `scatter`.

This **works** (with `scatter`): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqLbpr

This **does not work** (with `scattergl`): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzRLVY

Any idea?

Comment: See https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/130 for the most up-to-date list of plotly.js `scattergl` limitations,